# What happens when the command add-teamChannelUser in powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

When I do the command:

```
  Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupID $group -DisplayName "Blabla" -user $user
```

if the channel doesn't exist creates a new channel or simply says that is impossible to add the user to said channel?

Comment: `-User` should be a user's UPN (user principal name - e.g. johndoe@example.com) Is that the case here?

Comment: This question is getting down-voted because the OP is using a cmdlet ([Add-TeamChannelUser][1]) that is only available in the public preview of an older version of the module.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/Add-TeamChannelUser?view=teams-ps

Answer (score 0):

The above command

```
Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupID $group -DisplayName "Blabla" -user $user
```

returns the below error

```
 Add-TeamChannelUser : The term 'Add-TeamChannelUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupID $group -DisplayName "Blabla" -user $user
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Add-TeamChannelUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```